# Website deployed on AWS EC2 Using FileZilla isn't showing live changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, filezilla

My organization is using AWS and I connected to it using FileZilla.

Server Folder Path:

- Source
- -> Website Folder
- ---> Client
- ------> All files visible here which are things from the create-react-app

Specifically:

Build, Node_modules, Public, Src, and other files including Makefile

On my local computer I used npm install to gather the latest files, then I made some changes and when I finished I ran "Npm run build" and then copied over all folders including the new build folder.

I used drag and drop into the filezilla window.

Now when I check the live website for changes, it still shows the old information even though it's updated on my local build. I don't understand.

Is there another way to deploy this properly? I don't see why I can't drag and drop the source files over. It's just static changes.

Things I tried:

- Clearing Cache
- Using different browser
- Incognito
- Reconnecting to server via filezilla

Comment: Are you copying these files to a web server, or to Amazon S3?

Comment: I go to instances in aws, and then click on the instance running; and then connect to the public ipv4 dns address that serves the live website.

I then use Filezilla to connect to it there. From there I browse for the websitename/source/this directory and drag and drop the files there.

So maybe web server? I'm not too familiar. I overwrite the existing files so its suppose to work.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out. Only took forever.

The solution was to connect using ssh client and push transfer the files over directly.

I used putty to do this.